# C# multi threading add a thread after any another thread complete

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker

I am developing a document converter using winforms.

i want to use multi threading to convert 3 documents in parallel and any one of the document conversion finished then other document conversion has to be start as new thread.

i am trying to use multi thread but i am not able to find how to place threads in queue.

is there any way to implement this in c#.

Comment: Placing threads in a queue doesn't make a lot of sense. Try placing tasks in a queue and have threads work on them.

Comment: You could use threadpools

Comment: you should use threadpools and let the thread pool manager take care of managing threads or use the Task/Parallel library for more control but to be honest, I think the threadpool will work just fine as per your requirements here.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `Task`s for this. A lot of information can be found in MSDN [Task Parallelism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

In the simplest form you create Task objects and start them, after that you can use `Task.WhenAny()` to check if any of them have finished and start more. In the end you can use `Task.WhenAll()` to see when all tasks have finished.

You can also just create all tasks and let the system handle the concurrency, unless you specifically need three to run concurrently.

Answer (score 2):

As I understood, you are looking a way to process multiple documents in parallel with limited concurrency. You can use [Parallel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.aspx) class for this purpose.

```
ParallelOptions options=new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism=3 };
Parallel.ForEach(documentCollection,options,document => ConvertDocument(document));
```